# What's the purpose of these blue double V collectibles?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2

As far as I can tell every level has a blue double V collectible, but I'm not really sure what they do. I've collected a few of them, but I've never even gotten a message indicating I've collected one, let alone any indication what they do.

What's the purpose of these blue double V collectibles?

Comment: I think there's a challenge involving them. I've been wondering where I can see if I already collected it or not.

Comment: @miva2  Turns out there is a challenge, although it's rewards are a mystery.

Comment: @Wipqozn Do you have enough information to self-answer?

Comment: @Corsaka Not yet. I'd want to actually figure out what the rewards of this challenge are first. Now that I've found the challenge, though, I might be able to find something online. If you have an answer, though, I encourage you to post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every skate park in the game has secret collectibles. Collect a set from each park and you can clear some challenges.

The "Vicarious Visions" logos are just another one of the more obvious sets. Collect them all at each park and you get a profile logo, some experience, and cash.

[image]

Full listing of challenges could be found in the "Skate Park Challenges" under the "Secrets" tab.

Be warned that all secret challenges does not show you the progress for each park. So you'll need to keep track for yourself which parks you completed the challenge for.